# Use differentiation to find a power series representation for $f(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$

Tags: calculus

Need help on all steps. Use differentiation to find a power series representation for $$
f(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what happens if you start taking derivatives of $f$?

$$
f'(x) = \frac{-2}{(1+x)^3}
$$
$$
f''(x) = \frac{-2 \cdot -3}{(1+x)^4}
$$
$$
f'''(x) = \frac{-2 \cdot -3 \cdot -4}{(1+x)^5}.
$$

Do you see the pattern?
Can you guess the general form of $f^{(n)}(x)$?
Given the general form, what is $f^{(n)}(0)$?

Comment: "Use differentiation" points toward differentiating a series termwise.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you differentiate $-\frac{1}{1+x}$ ? You get $\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$. Try differentiating the series for $-\frac{1}{1+x}$.

Comment: This is an odd advice, because the power series for $\log$ is usually obtained by integrating the series for $1/(1\pm x)$ once (the latter being a geometric series).

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat No, if one is introducing Taylor series for the first time one computes it from the definition, i.e. one computes all the derivatives of $\log$. Likewise one does with $e^x$, $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$.